# What's the best way to set variables only if they haven't been defined in Python?

Tags: python, variables, discord.py

In my little game in a discord bot, this means I can't change `user` because it's given by the discord API, also the people who play the game enter commands in discord and don't execute the python file on their PC. I save the data of users in a json file and read the file to a dictionary when I need it. Now that I don't have to worry about `KeyError` when I try to read something from that dictionary, for example if I would try to read `player_data[user_id]["quests"]["end"]` but this wouldn't be defined, I call the function `setup` at the start of every command, which tests if the user's data is already saved:

```py
async def setup(user):
    global ITEMS
    with open("player_data.json", "r") as json_file:
        player_data = json.load(json_file)
    try:
        player = player_data[str(user.id)]
    except KeyError:
        player_data[str(user.id)] = {}
        player_data[str(user.id)]["inventory"] = {}
        for item in ITEMS:
            player_data[str(user.id)]["inventory"][item] = 0
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"] = {}
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"]["completed"] = "0"
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"]["running"] = False
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"]["start"] = None
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"]["end"] = None
        player_data[str(user.id)]["quests"]["duration"] = None
        player_data[str(user.id)]["trees"] = 2
        player_data[str(user.id)]["daily_claim"] = None
    with open("player_data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(player_data, json_file)
```

Now this has an obvious flaw:
If `player_data[str(user.id)] = {}` is defined, `player = player_data[str(user.id)]` won't raise a `KeyError` even if `player_data[str(user.id)]["trees"] = 2` wouldn't be defined. A solution to that would be if I would use `try:` and `except` for every single key in the dictionary, but this isn't very clean, so my question is, is there a better way to do this?

**What I have tried**

- Googling [python set every variable that is not defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20set%20every%20variable%20that%20is%20not%20defined&safe=active&rlz=1C1ONGR_deDE933DE933&sxsrf=ALeKk03Iw9jIeHo5xDDSOf77pt461M5Kgg%3A1622969436650&ei=XIy8YIOHJ9OB9u8P5ISPiAU&oq=python%20set%20every%20variable%20that%20is%20not%20defined&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEBYQHRAeOgcIABBHELADUN_j2wRYrevbBGCy7NsEaAFwAngAgAFpiAHnBJIBAzYuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiDpYKm0ILxAhXTgP0HHWTCA1EQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) and looking through the first 2 pages of results.
- Searching [[python] Define variable only if undefined](http://%5Bpython%5D%20Define%20variable%20only%20if%20undefined) on this site

Comment: you could define all variables with default values at start of game - ie. None - and later you don't have to worry about keys in dict. Or you should do it when you create new player - with new `user.id`

Comment: you can use `if key in dict` to create variable when it is not in dictionary. You can also use `collections.defaultdict()` to automatically create `{}` values when there is no `key`

Comment: It's not really obvious to me what you're trying to achieve. Why does `setup` first read- and then write to the same JSON file? It seems to me that you'd want to read from the JSON file whenever a user starts up the game, and wants to continue where they last left off, and you write to the file when they "save" the game and quit. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This is in a discord bot, so anyone would be able to execute a command and the user is the discord user so I don't create it. @furas

Comment: you could keep all these information directly in `user` - similar to `user.id` - and add method which generate dict with values to save in JSON file. And other function which get JSON from file and set values directly in `user`.

Comment: then you should check `if str(user.id) in player_data` and then create data for new user.

Comment: @furas `user.id` could be in `player_data` but maybe `player_data[str(user.id)]["trees"]` isn't declared. Also I can't change `user`  because it's given from the discord API

Comment: I am also not sure what you're trying to achieve. Is it possible that the user exists in `player_data.json` but without any data saved i.e. as `{}`? Or is it possible that only part of the variables exist? And if the user exists, do you want to overwrite the values or only values that do not already exist?

Comment: Yes, it could happen that only part of the variables exist, and if the user exists, I don't want to overwrite the values, I only want values that don't already exist @ptts

Comment: In that case, it sounds like your actual problem is "Merging nested dictionaries". You have your `default_data`, which is a nested dictionary (i.e. you have dictionaries within a dictionary) for example `quests`. Then you have the user data which you load from your json file.
You want to take your `default_data` and update each value with an existing one from your json file, if it exists.

Search for something like `python merge nested dictionaries` here or on Google.

Comment: as I said before: you could use `if str(user.id) in player_data` and if it doesn't exists then create ALL variables with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

def dict_merge(base_dct, merge_dct, add_keys=True):
    # Source: https://gist.github.com/angstwad/bf22d1822c38a92ec0a9#gistcomment-3077371
    rtn_dct = base_dct.copy()
    if add_keys is False:
        merge_dct = {
            key: merge_dct[key] for key in set(rtn_dct).intersection(set(merge_dct))
        }

    rtn_dct.update(
        {
            key: dict_merge(rtn_dct[key], merge_dct[key], add_keys=add_keys)
            if isinstance(rtn_dct.get(key), dict) and isinstance(merge_dct[key], dict)
            else merge_dct[key]
            for key in merge_dct.keys()
        }
    )
    return rtn_dct

ITEMS = ["item_1", "item_2"]
DEFAULT_PLAYER_DATA = {
    "inventory": {item: 0 for item in ITEMS},
    "quests": {
        "completed": "0",
        "running": False,
        "start": None,
        "end": None,
        "duration": None,
    },
    "trees": 2,
    "daily_claim": None,
}


# In this example I am using a variable instead of a file 
# as reading and saving the json is not part of your problem
player_data_file = {
    "1": {
        "inventory": {
            "item_1": 9999,
        },
        "trees": 9999,
    },
}


def setup(user):
    player_data_from_file = player_data_file.get(str(user.id), {})
    player = dict_merge(DEFAULT_PLAYER_DATA, player_data_from_file)
    player_data_file[str(user.id)] = player
    # This is where you would save the updated player_data_file file/variable
    return player
```

```py
user = User(1)
print(setup(user))
```

Result: `{'inventory': {'item_1': 9999, 'item_2': 0}, 'quests': {'completed': '0', 'running': False, 'start': None, 'end': None, 'duration': None}, 'trees': 9999, 'daily_claim': None}`

```py
user = User(3) # Does not exist in file
print(setup(user))
```

Result: `{'inventory': {'item_1': 0, 'item_2': 0}, 'quests': {'completed': '0', 'running': False, 'start': None, 'end': None, 'duration': None}, 'trees': 2, 'daily_claim': None}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to initialise `player_data[str(user.id)]` every time when either the entry doesn't exist or when it's an empty `dict`.

If that's the case, I would suggest something like the following, using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which returns `None` if the entry doesn't exist:

```py
async def setup(user):
    global ITEMS
    with open("player_data.json", "r") as json_file:
        player_data = json.load(json_file)

    user_id = str(user.id)
    if not player_data.get(user_id):
        player_data[user_id] = {
            "inventory": {item: 0 for item in ITEMS}
            "quests" = {
                "completed": "0"
                "running": False
                "start": None
                "end": None
                "duration": None
            }
            "trees": 2
            "daily_claim": None
        }

    with open("player_data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(player_data, json_file)
```

Comment: This still has the same problem as my previous attempt: if `player_data[user_id]["inventory"]` exists but ``player_data["trees"]` doesn't this doesn't add `trees`. The answer by ptts worked.